# Stop Google Analytics from appending hostname?

Tags: google-analytics

I've come across an Analytics profile that is appending the rest of a URL to the end of a page's path.

For example when looking at the page that exists at `http://example.com/page` I would expect to see `/page` but instead it shows me `/page/http://example.com/`.

The profile has no filters applied to it, and until July was reporting as expected (`/page`), in July the site in question switched hosts *(and absolutely nothing else, so I'm not sure that's the problem)*. The analytics code on the site is the standard Google Async code with a domain set. All other profiles for the site show `/page` as expected.

Any ideas as to how I can get the profile to function as expected?

Comment: If a domain is set in GA it's probably not set correctly.

Comment: It's set using `_gaq.push` (`_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);`). However, that was done very recently and this problem has been occurring for longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under "Profile Settings" the default page was set to be `http://example.com/` (shown below) where Analytics expects something like (`/`, `index.html`, or `home.php`).

[image: Google Analytics Profile Settings, Default page section screenshot]

The problem was fixed by removing the default page.